# NHibernate. Field update only on first save

Tags: nhibernate

How can I make NHibernate to update any field ONLY on first saving and not to update it on `session.Update(obj)`?

**EDIT:** For example, I have an entity `A`, that has reference to entity `B`, like:

```
public class A
{
    // ... some properties
    public virtual B PropB {get; set;}
}
```

After retrieving the instance of class `A` I save *all* its properties instead of `PropB` into fields on web page (including id and version). After user modified some fields and click 'Save' (herewith I am sure, that he *can not edit* `PropB`), I can just restore this object from the web page and save it to the database but I *can not* restore the linked `PropB`. So, when I save `A` instance, it looses link. So, because of `PropB` can not be modified by any way after first saving, I need a solution to restrict its updating.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What problem are you having exactly?  It's better to state the problem you are having AND what you want to do to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mapping attribute that effectively makes a property insert-only: `update="false"`.

However, there are two issues with your question:

1. `session.Update` does not update an entity, flushing the session does. You only need to call `session.Update` to attach entities that were not loaded by the session.
2. Why are you modifying a property you don't intend to update in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I would us DTO's in this case and update the entities within the transaction.

Pseudo-code:

```
public StoreB(ADto dto)
{
  using (transaction)
  {
    A entity = session.Get<A>(dto.Id);
    entity.PropB = dto.PropB;
    transaction.Commit();
  }
}

public StoreC(ADto dto)
{
  using (transaction)
  {
    A entity = session.Get<A>(dto.Id);
    entity.PropC = dto.PropC;
    transaction.Commit();
  }
}
```